# How to configure git config to use MacVim and zsh to use Vim bundled in MacVim?

Tags: macvim, git

The following is an excerpt of my `.gitconfig`

```
[core]
    editor = mvim
    autocrlf = false
    pager = less -FX
    commentchar = "#"
[diff]
    tool = vimdiff
    guitool = vimdiff
[merge]
    tool = vimdiff
    guitool = vimdiff
[mergetool "vimdiff"]
    layout = LOCAL,MERGED,REMOTE
```

within this setup, I encountered the following problems:

1. If I run `git --config --global --edit` I get the error: `error: cannot run mvim: No such file or directory error: unable to start editor 'mvim'` but output of `where mvim` is `mvim: aliased to /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim`. The problem is solved  by setting with `git --config --global core.editor vim` but this will use vim shipped with MacOS, which I don't want to use.
2. I read somewhere that MacVim ship with its own version of Vim, but when I run `where vim` I only obtain `/usr/bin/vim`. How to make vim to point to the Vim version bundled in MacVim (if any)?
3. `vimdiff` in `[diff]` and `[merge]` sections relate to vim shipped with MacOs. In the same line as in point 2., how to replace it to point to `vimdiff` bundled in MacVim? Note that output of `where vimdiff` is `/usr/bin/vimdiff`.

Macvim version is Vim 9.0.1276 (MacVim r176).
I installed MacVim through its binaries (not brew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvim` should be an actual script somewhere in your `$PATH`, not an alias.

With the way MacVim is currently built, it is as simple as prepending `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/` to your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin:$PATH
```

which will give you direct access to `vim`, `vimdiff`, `view`, etc. as well as `mvim`, `mvimdiff`, `mview`, etc.

As explained in… `:help mvim`, under `:help macvim`.

Also, note that the `vimdiff` in `merge.tool=vimdiff` is not "the `vimdiff` executable or alias or whatever in my `$PATH`". It refers to [a script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/mergetools/vimdiff) that is part of Git.

As explained in… https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-mergetool.

Comment: The command to get a local copy of the mergetool documentation is `git help mergetool`.

Comment: The one for `merge`, the one I linked to in the answer, is `$ git help merge`, though.

Comment: Fair enough; figured if we included `:help` style commands we could do similar for Git. The mergetool help also explains how to configure tool=vimdiff.

Comment: I agree on principle but Vim's documentation is heavily tagged, which makes it pretty easy to point to a specific section without overwhelming the user. It's not 100% bulletproof but it works for most cases. `man` and `info`, on the other hand… "Go read those three paragraphs" versus "Your answer is somewhere in those six hundred lines, go read them". Git's online help has a clear edge over `man`, here.